# Token de duracion larga API de visualización básica de Instagram con cUrls

Tags: curl, php8, facebook-api

Estoy intentando obtener Token de duración larga API de visualización básica de Instagram con el siguiente código:

curl -i -X GET "https://graph.instagram.com/access_token?grant_type=ig_exchange_token&client_secret={instagram-app-secret}&access_token={short-lived-access-token}"

Y me retorno lo siguiente: Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'access_token' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.

Comment: El código, incluyendo la respuesta o errores deben ir en formato texto y no en imágenes. Para postear imágenes ya existen las redes antisociales como Instagram. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta.